# Sceneform generates sfb files without colors

Tags: android, 3d, arcore, .obj, sceneform

I have problem with the objects generated from **Google Sceneform Tools ​(Beta)​ v1.13.0** in Android Studio.

I [downloaded](https://poly.google.com/view/22QmtJi62zQ) the object (**.obj file**) from poly and imported to **Blender** to change the dimensions. After that exported again as **.obj file**.

When I use it to generate **.sfb** file in **Android Studio** with Sceneform tools, the **.sfb** object that is generated is only black.

Left is  object (**.obj and .mtl**) imported in **Blender**, and right is generated **.sfb** file in AndroidStudio.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: I have checked this [link](https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/issues/209), but in my case **.obj** file starts with these lines:

```
mtllib object_ga_25.mtl
o Barrel
v 0.793174 1.064640 -0.168964
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure that you also export the texture (image file) that your 3D mesh requires. In my case, my `sample-data` directory looks like this:

[image]

After successful conversion of the 3D model into sfa/sfb file formats, you should then check on the [samplers](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/sceneform/sfa#replacing_or_adding_textures) array in the `sfa` file that defines the textures your mesh is using.

Here's my end result:

```
 samplers: [
  {
    file: 'sampledata\\Tex_Beagle.png',
    name: 'Tex_Beagle',
    pipeline_name: 'Tex_Beagle.png',
  },
],
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. In my example there were no png files but even in android studio the object was black when it is used in the app it has colors. On the other objects which were only 1 color the problem was that i did not included .png files that came together with the object. Thanks again.

Comment: Solved my issue. Thanks!